# ASP.NET required field validator firing on focus in firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, requiredfieldvalidator

I have 2 asp.net textboxes in an update panel. Both textbox controls have some javascript attached to autotab to the next field and to allow only numeric input. When I enter some data into the first field and press enter, focus shifts to the next field and the requiredfieldvalidator of the second field displays its "* required" error message, even though I've just entered the field. How can I prevent the validator from firing when I first enter the textbox?

I should also mention that both textboxes are in a gridview footer.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="add_ISBN" runat="server" Columns="14" MaxLength="17" CssClass="focus" />
<asp:TextBox ID="add_Qty" runat="server" Columns="4" MaxLength="4" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvQty" ControlToValidate="add_Qty" ErrorMessage="* required" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" ValidationGroup="Add" runat="server" />
```

In the codebehind:

```
 add_ISBN.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return isbnCheck(event, '" & add_Qty.ClientID & "')")
```

And the javascript:

```
function isbnCheck(e, id) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode

    if (validIsbnChars.indexOf(parseInt(key, 10)) >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (key == 13) {
            var nextfield = document.getElementById(id);
            if (nextfield) nextfield.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The javascript allows only a valid subset of characters, and if the user presses enter, sets focus to the next field.

Comment: You'll need to post some markup and your script so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by attaching the javascript to the onKeyPress event instead of onKeydown.

```
add_ISBN.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return isbnCheck(event, '" & add_Qty.ClientID & "')")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the bug is happening, but you can probably create a workaround using the [client-side validation mini-api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside).

Find the validator element on the page doing a `document.getElementById()`, and then set the `isvalid` flag to true on the validator when you tab into the field.

Alternately you could call `ValidatorEnable(validatorElement, false)` to disable it while you're in the field, and then re-enable it with `ValidatorEnable(validatorElement, true)` when you tab out.

Comment: Thanks womp. If it turns out there's no other way, I'll probably do something like this.